# Are there any scales (in any musical culture) that can contain non-fixed members (ones that can be sharped or flattened at will)?

Tags: scales, modes

I am wondering if there are any scales (that are in actual use) that also contain non-fixed pitches. By that I mean that in addition to having several fixed pitches, also have some "flexible" pitches that can be raised or lowered at will?

For example, are there any scales that can have either a raised or lowered scale-degree 3, where the descision whether to play a raised or a lowered 3rd is left at the discretion of the performer, and not prescripted by the scale itself?

Some examples of what I **AM NOT** after:

- In the melodic minor, scale-degrees 6 and 7 are raised on ascent and lowered on descent. Yet, in the context of either ascending or descending they DO have a fixed pitch.
- Similarly, in Indian music, the Arohana and Avarohana often contain different pitches, but those pitches are fixed in either context.
- Chromatic passing notes, which by definition are not intrinsically part of the scale.
- The use of modal mixture, that through some harmonic alteration may impact the notes of a melody.
- In the Klezmer scale Adonai malach (on C), there's an E natural when playing within the 1st octave of the scale, and an Eb when playing in the 2nd octave of the scale (see below). So the scale sometimes has E natural and sometimes Eb, but those too have very clear contexts, and in that sense those pitches are fixed as well.

[image]

Purely, to illustrate my point, I am attaching an example (below) of such scale (which I invented for the sake of explaining my question). This C scale, can make use of either E natural or Eb, as well as A natural and Ab interchangeably (at the discretion of the performer). In that sense, the scale itself contains some non-fixed pitches.

[image]

**Are there such scales in wide use anywhere?**

**UPDATE**
The Hindustani Raag Pilu (or Piloo) seems to fit the bill. Any other examples?

Comment: How close does musica ficta get to what you want? This involves unnotated, often optional accidentals.

Comment: As far as I know, musica ficta doesn't really leave any room for choice. I may be mistaken, but musica ficta MUST be enacted to abide by counterpoint rules and so, it an example of a non-flexible note that is inferred by context, but I wouldn't really call it a flexible note. What do you think?

Comment: A scale is just a set of notes which has been contrived by us. So chromatic would just about cover this.

Comment: @Tim A scale is much more than a contrived set of notes. It's a role granting musical framework that in some form or another is used ubiquitously across the world. As far as I know, the chromatic collection of notes is not used as a scale anywhere.

Comment: Exam boards would disagree with you there.

Comment: @Tim Ok, thank you. I'll let my PhD committee know that the last 5 years of my research should be disregarded because of a comment a guy wrote to me on the internet. But seriously, if you are curious, I'm happy to provide you with some hundreds of citable sources by reputable scholars from across the world and throughout the centuries.

Comment: Isn't it mostly a matter of how we define a scale? If your non-fixed example had an optional b7 as well, it would have all the notes of a major scale as well as the notes of the parallel minor. Using both in the same piece [isn't uncommon](https://youtu.be/Cf5iPS3-Oug?t=309). We could call it modulating between different fixed scales, or say that we are exercising our performer/composer discretion to use different subsets of a flexible scale that contains both sets of notes. Amounts to the same thing, doesn't it?

Comment: Likewise, anything that can be described as borrowing notes or chords from elsewhere should have an equivalent description as using a flexible scale that includes the borrowed parts as optional elements.

Comment: @j-g-faustus what you are referring to is a case of modal mixture, where two fixed modes  are used interchangeably. This is usually the result of borrowing harmonies (and then melodies follow suit). In this sense, this isn't exactly what I'm after, but I should have been more explicit in my original question. Let me update. Thanks for taking the time to contribute some thoughts!!

Comment: I keep on saying "Don't believe a lot of what you see on the 'net" so why be sarcastic? As it stands, the question is (to me) vague.  And what constitutes a scale, in your opinion, anyway? A set of notes which ..?

Comment: @Tim A scale (unlike a set), is a collection of notes that are bound by hierarchical relations, where usually there's a central "tonic" or "final" note, and a "dominant" or "recitation" note. And where, certain notes have certain tonal tendencies (like, say, the way a leading tone pulls up). In that, and in many other senses, a scale is not just arbitrary collection of notes you can pull out of a hat. Some combination of notes can bind to form scales, and others, no matter how much you try, will never be able to form those intrinsic relationships.

Answer (score 4):

I would be willing to bet that there are many throughout different cultures but what immediately comes to mind for me is the way I sometimes improvise over blues. I use an unofficial composite scale made up of combining parallel major and minor pentatonic scales and adding the #4/b5 blues note as well. It’s possible or even likely this scale has a name, I’ve never researched it. It looks like this in the key of C:

[image]

This scale allows for playing either major or minor pentatonic lines and also chromatic lines utilizing notes from both scales combined. It is completely chromatic from the D to the G. I even sometimes add extra chromatic passing notes between the ^5 and ^6 and also the ^b7 and ^1. The bottom line is you can use whichever notes you like at your discretion depending on whether you want a major or minor tonality or a more chromatic style.

Comment: I had thought about something like this as well. Can you think of any recorded or notated examples? I know I definitely heard that E and Eb played interchangeably in the context of blues, but an obvious example doesn't come to mind.

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich If you combine the blues scale with the bebop scale, then the available pitches are ^1, ^2, b^3, ^3, ^4, #^4, ^5, b^6, ^6, b^7, ^7, ^8. If you want recorded examples, jazz. "Giant Steps", perhaps. But that's just a fixed scale that has a lot of flexibility. There are contexts wherein a musician can use all 12 notes in a piece. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich There are so many but the intro to “Straighten up and Fly Right” by the Nat Cole Trio immediately comes to mind. ^b3 ^3 ^1 etc. There are also countless examples of blues/rock guitarists playing major pentatonic scales on the I chord then switching to a minor pentatonic on the IV chord.

Comment: Yes, this is a 'scale' that I use a lot. And I'm certain a lot of blues/jazz players do too. Basically every chromatic note, bar the two either side of the root. But even those come out to play sometimes! B as part of the Bebop, and C# as a kind of tts. I tell students that any note in any piece at any time is ripe for use, they just have to know how to play it. +1.

Comment: @Tim you are right in that every note in the chromatic scale can be useful in certain situations. Some may think that some of the notes will only function as passing tones and many times they do but even the C# (in C) can be the leading tone of the V/ii and the B can be the leading tone of the V chord.

Comment: So that's it then. The chromatic scale. And for those who can play notes 'in the cracks', include them too!

Comment: And - C# is the Blue note for V of  key C !  Let alone B being the major third note of the same. So that's all covered. That's if one decides a scale is comprised of notes used in a piece...

Comment: Also, the blue note is often “bent,” giving a range of options for exact intonation

Comment: This is a wonderful discussion. Just want to chime in and say that I don't consider a passing chromatic note as belonging to the scale. So while non-scale notes may appear in the context of music, as long as they are non-scale notes, then they are.... non-scale notes.

Comment: One great example I found so far is the Pilu Raga from the hindustani musical tradition. In it, E, A, and B, can appear both as natural or flattened notes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilu_(raga)

Answer (score -1):

A scale, by definition, is fixed.  But there's this thing called 'chromatic notes'.   A jazz player may interpret the chord 'C major' by basically using notes of the C major scale, but making frequent additional use of E♭ and G♭.  It isn't a new scale, E♮ and G♮ are still used, but other notes are too.